# RoR : Mongoid and form create hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Simple question for Rails gurus. Why I do have to use the following statement to insert a new Mongoid document : params[:video][:description] in the following create method of my VideosController? Why I can't use the params[:description] from the POST form? If I use it, the value becomes nil.

```
def create
    @video = Video.new(
        :title => params[:video][:title],
        :description => params[:video][:description]
    )
    if @video.save
        render 'success'
    else
        render 'error'
    end
end
```

Here is the Video.rb class :

```
class Video
    include Mongoid::Document

    field :title, type: String
    field :description, type: String

    validates_presence_of :title
    validates_presence_of :description

    acts_as_url :title
end
```

And finaly the form view :

```
<%=  form_for @video do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>

    <p/>

    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>

    <%= submit_tag("Enqueue video") %>

<% end %>
```

I don't quite get why the form input are video[description] and not just description as expected :

```
<label for="video_title">Title</label>
<input id="video_title" name="video[title]" type="text" />

<p/>

<label for="video_description">Description</label>
<input id="video_description" name="video[description]" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using `form_for`:

> Creates a form that allows the user to create or update the attributes
>   of a **specific model object**.

In your case, `Video` model. To understand Rails convention:

```
<%=  form_for @video do |f| %>
...
<%= f.text_field :description %>
...
```

Which results in an html  tag whose name attribute is **video[description]**. This means that when the form is submitted, the value entered by the user will be available in the controller as **params[:video][:description]**.

The `params` variable is an instace of `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess`, like a `Hash` with a small difference, according to documentation:

> This class has dubious semantics and we only have it so that people
>   can write **params[:key]** instead of **params[‘key’]** and they get the same
>   value for both keys.

Your `params` is something like:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"post",
 "authenticity_token"=>"xxx",
 "video"=>
  {"description"=>"Video desc"}
}
```

Where `"video"` or `:video` is one of the keys of the Hash. So, `params[:video]` is equivalent to `params.fetch("video")` which value is `{"description"=>"Video desc"}`. As you can see the value is another Hash. Finally to get the value of the description you have to `params[:video][:description]` (The Rails way) or `params.fetch("video").fetch("description")`, which value is `"Video desc"`.

`fetch` is a Ruby method of `Hash`: "Returns a value from the hash for the given key."

Taking this into account:

```
Video.new(params[:video]) = Video.new(:description => "Video desc") = Video.new(:description => params[:video][:description])
```

It's easier to use conventions, but for sure you can have `params[:description]` (just in case):

```
<%=  form_for @video do |f| %>
...
<%= text_field_tag :description %>
...
```

Note that I'm using `text_field_tag` instead of `f.text_field`. In this case the html tag name will be `description` in the `params` Hash you will receive `{ "description" => 'Video desc" }`...

Take a look to [Rails API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) to understand different helpers, etc. And also review your server's log.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use video[:description]. Create your form like this

```
<%=  form_for @video do |f| %>

   ....

    <p/>

    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_field :description, :name => "description" %>

   ....

<% end %>
```

Rails form_for helper name the input elements such that it becomes easy to push them into model attributes in one go like this

```
@video = Video.new(params[:video])
```

so that you don't have to do it like the way you have done

```
@video = Video.new(
        :title => params[:video][:title],
        :description => params[:video][:description]
    )
```

Comment: There will also be a bunch of stuff at the top level of `params` (such as `:action`, which button was pressed, ...) that the model doesn't care about.