# What does the params rails object consist of.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know I can access GET and POST parameters through params object.
I am though reading the getting started guide and cannot realize what does
the params[:post] comes from.
How does the params object is been formed in each case GET and POST.

```
@post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#the-first-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep reading the guides... they discuss it here in section 4 - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425327/ror-mongoid-and-form-create-hash/18540785#18540785). In my answer I explain with an example what's `params` and how it works.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

### How does the params object is been formed in each case GET and POST ?

Whenever you inherit your controller from `ApplicationController`, its respective module is included. So, `params` method is available to you.

### What does the params rails object consist of ?

It consist of `Hash` which are passed. The `permit` type of methods are just for protecting you from  `mass-assignment`