# Small form to move associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got a group which has many clients.
The moment the user wants to delete the group, he's obligated to move the clients of that group to a different group.

So i've created a little form. But I already know it's wrong. but I don't know how I should do it otherwise.

I want the form to be caught by my disband_group method in my groups controller. Extract the move_to ID etc.

This is what I have now. Which doesn't work.
(it says `param not found: group` on `params.require(:group)` which is no big surprise)

```
<%= form_for(@group) do |f| %>
    <%= select_tag('move_to', options_for_select(current_user.groups.collect{ |u| [u.name, u.id] }), :prompt => "Choose") %>
    <%= f.submit "Move" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

- The select_tag needs to be changed to `f.select`. That should do the trick.
- After that if it still does not work, put a `1/0` as the first line in the method to check the parameters coming in. This will throw an exception and the page will display the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Add a route to your `disband_group` action (add the correct path):

```
post '/disband_group' => "groups#disband_group", :as => :disband_group
```

And then modify your form pointing to the disband_group action:

```
<%= form_for(:group, url: disband_group_path) do |f| %>
    <%= f.select :move_to, options_for_select(current_user.groups.collect{ |u| [u.name, u.id] }), :prompt => "Choose") %>
    <%= f.submit "Move" %>
<% end %>
```

This will add send the move_to param as follows: `"group" => { "move_to" => "3" }`

Take a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425327/ror-mongoid-and-form-create-hash/18540785#18540785) to understand how the form works.